# Firefox shifting with vertical align and border bottom

Tags: css, firefox

This css is causing the text to shift upwards in Firefox when rolled over but not in other browsers

```
#element{
height:40px;
}

#element a,img{
vertical-align:middle;
}

#element a{
font-size:16px;
color:#d1d1d1;
text-decoration:none;
}

#element:hover a{
border-bottom: #fff 1px dotted;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Makes sense to me. You are adding a border of 1px width. This will change the dimensions of the element. A simple solution is to have a permanent border and just change its color:

```css
#element a {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #d1d1d1;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom-style: dotted;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-color: transparent;
}

#element:hover a {
   border-bottom-color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: It makes sense to me to but the other browsers don't behave that way, I will do the color as a fix though.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: inline-block;` and `margin-bottom: -1px;` to compensate for the extra pixel on the bottom on hover.

```
#element:hover a{
  border-bottom: #fff 1px dotted;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this got downvoted. It solves the original problem and works consistently in FF, Chrome, and IE. Negative margins are not a hack (http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/), and inline-block just adds block-like behavior to `a` elements without screwing up their `inline` behavior. Or am I missing something obvious?